# kdevelop - two windows

Tags: linux, ide, kde-plasma, kdevelop

Is It possible to have got two  windows in the Kdevelop? I have got two LCDs. 
I wish i could have a debug information on the first and the code on the second one.

It will be really helpful for me.

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried starting two instances of kdevelop? Debug in one, program in the other?

There is also a small button to disconnect some panels from the main one, they will become their own window.

Comment: it will be so cumbersome and what about two tabs?